# Ubuntu 22.04 not recognizing speaker of headphone

Tags: 22.04, microphone, headphones

My laptop model was ROG M16 and my headset was Sony WH-1000XM5. Ubuntu was able to output audio through my headset, but did not recognize my headphone's speaker. I tried to add `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi` to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` but it did not work. I was not sure what was the right `model` value to set here. Any idea? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't recognize the microphone?

Comment: @Terrance No it does not. Tried to fix it following existing solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: You have not told us any solutions that you have tried.  You only list that you tried to add it.  I would suggest that you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1487659/edit) your question and add details like solutions that you have tried, and also fix that it is not recognizing your microphone instead of the speaker.  Speakers are the things that go on your ears.